# Can Joomla with MySql manage 500,000 users and records

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I am developing a mobile which will be managed by Joomla as a backend. I am expecting about 500,000 monthly return users by 6 months after launch.

What I want to know if Joomla on a shared hosting can handle 500,000 users and over 2 millions user files.. The user files are created by them and can be accessed by any of the users.. averagely a user can query about 10 files a day from the database...

Thank you

Comment: Also posted at: http://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/16377/120

Answer (score 2):

The question you should be asking is "Can my host and server manage 500,000 users and records?"

Joomla with MySql won't have issues if you have the right hosting and server resources. (but that's not going to be a shared hosting server which has lots of resource limitations and low bandwidth for a single site)

Comment: I what i want to find out is the capacity of Joomla especially on a share hosting

Comment: That is a hosting specific question that is completely dependent on the environment details for the shared host.

Here is a link to a non-exhaustive list of shared hosts. you will have to contact each individually to find out what their resource limits are.
http://phpversions.info/shared-hosting/